# Checking whether a matrix is a permuted Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

Given a $n\times n$ matrix $M=(m_{ij})$. Is there any result about whether there exists a Toeplitz matrix $N$ and a permutation matrix $P$ such that $M=PNP^{-1}$?

Comment: A necessary (but not sufficient) condition: the matrix must have a constant diagonal

Comment: @Ben Grossman Thanks, i am interested in a sufficient condition.